# What isolation level do I need for these invariants to hold?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, `TabelA` and `TabelB`. Both have an `ID` column that is the primary key. In addition, `TabelB` has an `A_ID` column. The other columns are not relevant here.

```
create table TableA (
    ID serial primary key,
    ...,
)
create table TableB (
    ID serial primary key,
    A_ID integer not null references TableA(ID),
    ...,
)
```

For each row in `TabelA` there can be many rows in `TableB` that refer to it using the `A_ID` column. That means, the rows in `TableA` and `TableB` have a parent-child relationship.  I want to be able to replace a row in `TableA` and all its associated rows in `TableB` (i.e. the whole "family") in a transaction.

The SQL for replacing a row with `ID=old_id` looks like this:

```
delete from TableA where ID=old_id;
delete from TableB where A_ID=old_id;
insert into TableA values (default, ...);
-- get the new id somehow
insert into TableB values (default, new_id, ...), (default, new_id, ...), ...;
```

(The ellipses stand for the rest of the columns.)

Which isolation level do I need to set to guarantee that if two transaction executing this code overlap, the following holds after they finish:

1. There is no row in `TableA` with `ID=old_id`.
2. All rows in `TableB` have an `A_ID` that also appears in the `ID` column of `TableA` (in particular, there are no rows in `TableB` with `A_ID=old_id`).
3. Only one of the transactions inserted exactly one row in `TableA`.
4. Only one of the transactions inserted any rows into `TableB` and all of them have `A_ID=new_id` where `new_id` is the `ID` of the row inserted in 3.

I'm also open to suggestions to change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for the first requirement of yours you need a form of serializable isolation because anything else can have rows appear at any time. An anomaly could arise if you delete all existing rows and the next milliseconds someone inserts new rows.

See "[Phantom Reads](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html)". Note, that the <9.1 "SERIALIZABLE" level in Postgres does not provide serializability as the docs explicitly call out.

Comment: A proper serializable transaction level is available in Postgres 9.2.

Comment: Is it possible to change the code or the tables such that REPEATABLE READ is enough?

Comment: You could introduce a lock table with a single column "ID". When you start processing you insert old_id into it. Only one tran can do this at a time so you have achieved mutual exclusion. This serializes the transactions. When you're done you delete the lock row. Note, that REPEATABLE READ is a synonym for SERIALIZABLE in postgres. But you can use READ COMMITTED.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the rows of TableB before the rows of TableA. Also, A_ID should be a proper foreign key. You *could* then create this key with cascade, so that deleting from TableA automatically cascades to TableB (and deletes the records), but I personally find this a bit scary with complexer DB schemes and do the deletes in reverse programmatically.

A simple `BEGIN` before and `COMMIT` after the delete/insert block should suffice. Anything which starts before this block completes will see the database in its old state, anything after will see the new state.